# Http on apache to https on nginx

Tags: http, nginx, https, server, apache2

How do I redirect my http://example.com website on apache to https://www.example.com website on nginx.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must add A record (in DNS config) for www.example.com transfer for nginx website. But it not OK for clients and SEO overall. And the second A record must be for example.com on apache website.

After or before adding of DNS record you must check Apache config for example.com - apache website must work for example.com only.